# Add row to table with ajax jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/plan",
    dataType: "json",
    ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status == "OK" && data.body != "") {
            var newRow = $("<tr><td>" + data.body.base.address + "</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td></tr>");
            $("#titleRow").after(newRow);
            return TINY.box.show({
                html: $('#workList').html(),
                animate: false,
                close: true,
                boxid: 'error',
                top: 10
            });
        } else {
            alert("Fail");
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
    <!-- the title row -->
    <tr id="titleRow">
        <th>案件番号</th>
        <th>住所</th>
        <th>施主名</th>
        <th>日付</th>
        <th>ステータス</th>
        <th>担当者</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- end title row --> 
    <!-- content row-->                      
    <!-- end content row -->
</table>
```

I want a row is added after `#titleRow` but 6 rows are added. I don't know why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: When/how is it called?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple `#titleRow` ids.

Comment: @Dmonix ID selector only selects one element.

Comment: please describe in detail what you want also add the html code in your question

Comment: I think your function is being called 6 times. You need to show how it's being bound to events.

Comment: @user1486067 Edit it into the question so you can use code formatting rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: @Dmonix ID: only one #titleRow

Comment: @dianuj: I want to add a row after titleRow(#titleRow) but i can't. I don't know why ajax does a loop.

Comment: @Jon: when i click on the button this function'll be called.

Comment: @user1486067 can  you pls post how do you launch the ajax request? there is no problem in the code you posted

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed that problem.

Answer (score 0):

here you are adding 1 row and 6 columns i can't see the problem:

```
var newRow = $("<tr><td>" + data.body.base.address + "</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td><td>hi</td></tr>");
            $("#titleRow").after(newRow);
```

maybe you lanched 6 times your Ajax so you get 6 rows instead of 1

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i only call this function once time. is it same with your mean?

Comment: @user1486067 what i mean is you need to post the code it launches this ajax request, cause maybe you are launching this request 6 times, anyway the code you posted is ok

Comment: Base.onSearchBtn = function() {//my code here } .P/S: only once time at here

Comment: @user1486067 and when you call the Base.onSearchBtn ?

Comment: @user1486067 you're welcome, do not forget to check my answer if it helps you ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed that problem.

Comment: @user1486067 you're welcome! :) if you found my answer helpfull please accept it ;) have a nice day!